# ASP.net __doPostBack is Refreshing my Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

It seems that one of my `__doPostBack` methods (on a `LinkButton`) is refreshing the javascript on my page... which is causing some of my `<div>`s to be hidden... any advice on how I can avoid this?

**Code:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="_lnkRefreshImage" OnClick="_lnkRefreshImage_Click"  CssClass="refreshImage" CausesValidation="false">Refresh</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: what is `s` ?  And what is `_lnkRefreshImage_Click` ?

Comment: You can avoid this by not using `<asp:x>` controls, at all, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript runs in the browser, but the `__doPostBack` method causes the page to post back to the server - you can't expect the Javascript to retain state when this happens, not without "help".

You have different options:

- Change the `div` elements to be server side and set their visibility on the server side
- Have a hidden input that holds the visibility state of the different `div`s and in your javascript query it on page load to set the visibility
- Not use a `LinkButton` but some client side markup so a postback doesn't occur
- Use AJAX to communicate with the server

Comment: Thanks Oded. __doPostBack doesn't completely refresh the page... just the update panel and (apparently) the javascript. Can I still use a hidden input field event if its not a complete refresh?

Comment: option 1 and 2 are hacks. Option 4 is use ajax instead of `__doPostBack`

Comment: @AdamStorr - I see, you are using AJAX. A hidden field will still work. Though I am surprised that the Javascript is reset. Do you mean that the elements are reloaded without the visiblity set by javascript?

Comment: @Oded - That is exactly what is happening... my elements are losing visibility.

Comment: @AdamStorr - In that case, you need to reapply the visibility code again after the AJAX fires, that's all. Possibly add a call to this piece of code at the end of the update panel (not sure if that will work).

Comment: I removed the LinkButton and used a basic <input> field with a click event to perform the postback and confirm the visibility... but that didn't work.

Comment: @AdamStorr - You are doing a full postback, so that's what I'd expect.